# FusedLocationProviderClient doesn't work with android 5.1

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an application with Google Places API and Google Maps API. User can pick up place and open it on MapView later. After some testing I found out that FusedLocationProviderClient doesn't work on every device as expected. It works fine on Android 8.1(Redmi Note 5), but not on 5.1(Meizu m3 note). The problem in 5.1 is that LocationCallbackListener never gets called.
Here is code:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap
        mLocationRequest.interval = 60000
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 60000
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
        mLocationCallback = LocationCallbackListener()

        val placeLatLng = LatLng(mPlaceLatLng.first, mPlaceLatLng.second)
        mGoogleMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(placeLatLng).title(mPlaceName).snippet(mPlaceAddress))
        mGoogleMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(placeLatLng, 15.0f))

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
                mGoogleMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            } else {
                PermissionHelper.checkFineLocationPermission(requireActivity())
            }
        } else {
            mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
            mGoogleMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

And I have a

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In my manifest.

GooglePlaces API is not displaying device location too. So, I guess I can't get access to location in any API

Comment: have you solved this

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran No, I didn't